# Changing UUID with tune2fs gives "NOT A DIRECTORY" ERROR

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I had a self-inflicted complete failure on my Ubuntu 15.10 partition (`/dev/sda5`).  I had a complete backup using [Systemback](https://sourceforge.net/projects/systemback/), which I installed successfully after booting to the LiveCD.  As happens when I completely reinstall Ubuntu on the partition using either Systemback or tar, the UUID was changed and I get this error:

```
No controller found
No caching mode found:
Gave up waiting for root device.....
Alert! /dev/disk/by-uuid/####-####-#### (i.e., the UUID) does not exist.  Dropping into a shell.
(initramfs)
```

To fix this, I usually boot into the LiveCD and perform the following:

```
sudo tune2fs /dev/sda5 -U ####-####-#### (i.e., the UUID)
```

However, I am now getting a very scary error:

```
tune2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
tune2fs: Not a directory while trying to open /dev/sda5/
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

*Can this be overcome -- either by getting tune2fs to work or by using an alternative way to change the UUID???*  I have searched everywhere for the `Not a directory while trying to open` error in conjunction with tune2fs, and have come up with nothing.

Aaaarggghh!

- **NOTE**: I also tried to update the UUID manually in `/etc/fstab` and /boot/grub/grub.cfg then chrooting into `/dev/sda5` and updating
  grub -- it didn't work!!

Comment: The error says `/dev/sda5/` with a trailing slash - are you sure of the command you typed? O.o Anyway, instead of changing the filesystem UUID, why not change the UUID in `/etc/fstab` to the new one?

Comment: Thanks muru...I am away from the computer at the moment -- but I need to check that trailing slash!!!  I think you may be right.  I certainly hope so.  Will report back when I get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **trailing slash** was the culprit! What a stupid mistake. Thanks so much for catching it. I did also have to change the `/etc/fstab` UUID, because using `tune2fs` only changed the partition id, not the `fstab`. Thanks again.